# Фильтрация, сортировка и поиск данных в quasar через graphq и hasura

Tags: graphql, quasar-framework

У меня есть проект написанный на фрейморке quasar, где БД подключена через Hasura.

В скрипт я прописала вывод моей БД. Мне необходимо сделать фильтрацию, сортировку и поиск.

Видео материалов и статей по нужным мне фрейморкам очень мало, а то и вообще нет.

Я не понимаю как мне обратиться в qusar, чтобы вытащить определенные данные и сделать нужные мне пункты.

Приложу ссылку с GitHub, чтобы было удобнее прочитать код и помочь мне.

https://github.com/Frenky99/Sprint-testing